# Avoiding unneccessry recompilations using "branchy" development model

Tags: c++, mercurial

I'm using Mercurial for development of quite a large C++ project which takes about 30 minutes to get built from the scratch(while incremental builds are very quick).

I'm usually trying to implement each new feature in the new branch(using "hg clone") and I may have several new features developed during the day and it's quickly getting very boring to wait for the new feature branch to get built.

Are there any recipes to somehow re-use object files from other already built branches?

P.S. in git there are named branches within the same repository which make re-usage of the existing object files possible for the build system, however I prefer the simpler Mercurial separate branches model...

Comment: I agree that multiple clones are a great way to keep the overview. However, I would like to note (as it is also noted below) that Mercurial does support several branches of development in the same clone, just like Git does.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's not that convenient as git local branches and not available "out-of-the-box", is it?

Comment: @pachanga: Well, my point is that Mercurial has always supported supported having multiple lines of development in the same repository. They show up as multiple heads. So I can pull stuff from another repo, look at it and then continue with my work. When I'm ready, I can merge the two branches or I can remove the other branch if I don't like it. The bookmarks extension (bundled with Mercurial) lets you name the heads, if needed. However, Mercurial 1.3 still wont let you browse or clone bookmarks over the network like Git does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [Localbranch extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LocalbranchExtension) was designed partly around this use case. It uses a single working directory, but I think it's simpler than git. It's essentially a mechanism for maintaining multiple repository clones under one working directory, where only one is active at a given time.

Comment: BTW, I'm a bit lost - there is also bookmarks extension which seems to be doing pretty much the same job... Could you please explain the difference?

Comment: The basic difference is that localbranch creates completely separate repository clones underneath the working directory, whereas bookmarks are pointers to different revisions in a single shared repository. Bookmarks are more like what git does, but because the hg repository format doesn't really support garbage collection the way git's does, you can't easily remove a "bookmark" branch from your repo the way you could delete a clone, and for instance hg log will look odd because the revisions of the different bookmarks will be intermingled.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) as a way to speed up compilation of (mostly) the same code tree. The way it works is as following:

- You define a place to be used as the cache (and the maximum cache size) by using the `CCACHE_DIR` environment variable
- Your compiler should be set to `ccache ${CC}` or `ccache ${CXX}`

ccache takes the output of `${CC} -E` and the compilation flags and uses that as a base for its hash. As long as the compiler flags, source file and the headers are all unchanged, the object file will be taken from cache, saving valuable compilation time.

Note that this method speeds up compilation of any source file that eventually produces the same hash. If you share source files across projects, ccache will handle them as well.

If you already use `distcc` and wish to use it with ccache, set the `CCACHE_PREFIX` environment variable to `distcc`.

Using ccache sped up our source tree compilation around tenfold.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to speed up your builds could be to use a local "build directory" on your disk. This way you can checkout into this directory and start the build. The first time it will take the full time, but after that it will (hopefully) only rebuild the files where the source code changed.

Answer (score 2):

Woops, I missed your P.S. where you don't like having multiple named branches in the same repo and that you prefer separate clones.. sorry about that.

<strike>I too have somewhat large C++ projects and the clone-per-feature workflow didn't work for me very well.  Firstly, I had to close down my Vim session and then reopen (many of the same) files once I've created the clone.  Secondly, like you said, a lot of code must be recompiled unnecessarily.  Thirdly, I have to keep track of where I've pushed to and pulled from - gets confusing when you start a new feature and then get sidetracked onto a new one. Before you know it you have many clones and not sure which ones need to be pushed back to your main.</strike>

You definitely don't want to use named branches (as I'm sure you know) to handle this as they are quite permanent.

What you need are bookmarks: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BookmarksExtension

Bookmarks allow you to create lightweight (and otherwise anonymous) branches per feature by facilitating the naming of heads in your repo.  These heads would normally be unnamed and you would have to look at the output of 'hg log' or use some graphical tool to find the revision numbers for the tip of your feature-branch.  With bookmarks you can name them descriptive names like 'my-cool-feature' or 'bugfix-392'.

If you like the idea of bookmarks, I'd also recommend my own extension called 'tasks': http://bitbucket.org/alu/hgtasks.  This extension works like bookmarks but adds some more functionality.  It allows you created feature-branches (now called tasks) and suppress the pushing of incomplete tasks.  This is handy when you have a few feature-branches at once.  You may not be ready to push your 'my-cool-feature' task, but 'bugfix-392' is ready to go.  Because tasks track a set of changesets (and not just one 'tip' changeset) there are some things you can do with tasks that you can't with bookmarks.  See an example workflow here: http://x.zpuppet.org/2009/03/09/mercurial-tasks-extension/.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial also has local named branches, see the hg branch command.

If you insist on using hg clone to do branchy development, I guess you could try creating a folder link (shortcut under windows) in your repo to a shared obj folder. This will work with hg clone, but I'm not sure your build tool will pick it up.

Otherwise, you probably keep all your repos in one folder - just put your obj folder there (it shouldn't be under source control anyways, imo). Use relative paths to refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think sharing a separate directory for object files should really work.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning: many .o symbol tables (or equivalent) contain the full path name of the source file. If that other file changes (or if the path is not visible from the new directory) you may encounter weirdness when debugging.